# In ASP.NET Webforms, ChangePassword: how do I set SuccessTemplate to visible after password's been changed?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, change-password

It does allow me to change the password but the view is reset to its original state.

OnInit looks like this:

```
changePassword.ChangingPassword += ChangePasswordButton_Click;
```

and the method implementation:

```
private void ChangePasswordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
 MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();

 string oldPassword = changePassword.CurrentPassword;
 string newPassword = changePassword.NewPassword;

 try
 {
  if (user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword))
  {
   //TODO: set successtemplate to visible. How? Who knows.
   //Response.Write("Changes were successful");
  }
  else
  {
   //Response.Write("Failed to change password");
  }
 }
 catch (ArgumentException e)
 {
  //Response.Write("Password could not be changed due to: " + e.Message);
 }
}
```

I do get to change the password when I'm supposed to, so it does pickup the membership provider configuration.

I have both a SuccessTemplate and a ChangePasswordTemplate in the aspx file but I don't know how to make the ChangePassword control display the SuccessTemplate. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved:

```
changePassword.SuccessTemplate.InstantiateIn(changePassword);
changePassword.ChangePasswordTemplateContainer.Visible = false;
```